# Class as callback in JS?

Tags: javascript, class

I need to do 3 things.

```
$('#blah').click(TheFunc);

if(cond)
    TheFunc.Call($('#blah').get(0)) //adds a this object to the function call

$('#thing').click(function() {
    TheFunc.IsItInAReadyState()
```

I'm not exactly how to make this into a class. I'd like to A) Have it used in a callback which can use a `this`. Use .call on it so I can feed it `this` and finally access a function inside of it to see if the function is finished all its internal callbacks and processing all the data needs to and such.

I have a few global variables and I don't want to which is why I want to wrap all the data in a class. The problem is mostly that there are a lot of callbacks and thats why I need the 3rd use. The first two are just to kick off the processing.

Comment: Do you mean `call`, lowercase?

Comment: demo code is far to simplistic to figure out what you are trying to connect with it. Also context of `this` within `TheFunc` is not clear. Is already the jQuery element so not sure what you are wanting

Comment: also may want to look at jQuery  `deffered` API to monitor callback progress

Comment: To avoid globals, you can just wrap the whole thing in an IIFE (self-executing function), like `(function() { /* code here */ }())`. But I'm not sure what your 3d use case is, could you add more info?

Comment: @bfavaretto: Well the issue with wraping it is how do I access it from the #thing click event? Which is what the 3rd one is about. Accessing the internal data. I just wanted to use a function instead of doing a bunch of && logic on the `TheFunc.IsItInAReadyState` (which should actually be in an if)

Comment: @charlietfl: TheFunc wants this as a plain dom object which is why I use `.get(0)`. I figured out how to do this actually. I used `this.var` and `new` which is something new to me in javascript

Comment: `this` inside an event handler is DOM element, not jQuery